# How to edit .exe files to change 3 ip in this exe file

Tags: hex, editor, exe

I need help too. I encounter a problem that I cannot solve by myself with hex editor.
I am developing a server for a game, the server is up and running. the only problem I have is that it doesn't change the ips correctly in this exe file.
I tried all the tutorials found on youtube and without results.
if someone has a good soul and wants to help me by helping me, explaining or offering me another solution, I would be grateful.

I tried with the hex editor, but as I add the IP, other characters from this file disappear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.